# How to sum values in a row?

Tags: python

I have a .csv file that looks like this:

```
Word,2000,2001,2002,Total  
alpha,1,1,1  
beta,0,1,1  
charlie,0,0,1
```

I want to add the total value to each row. So far my code looks like this:

```
with open (myfile, 'r') as fin:
    for row in fin:
        total = []
        line = 0

        for num in row:
            if num.isdigit():
                line += num

        total.append(line)

        with open (myfile, 'a') as fout:
            fout.write(',' + total)
```

Two problems:

1. I don't want it to calculate a total of the years in the header row.
2. I get the following error message relating to the `line += num` code:

   ```
   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'
   ```

Comment: You have to convert `total` to a string so you can concatenate it: `fout.write(',' + str(total))`

Comment: Get in the habit of questioning your assumptions. Put `print(num)` as the first line of the `for` loop, and you'll see that you are not iterating over comma-separated fields, but over individual characters. Also, there is a difference between the string `"1"` and the integer value of `1`, even if `"1".isdigit()` returns `True`.

Comment: If you're working with a csv or tables in general, I recommend checking out Pandas (https://pandas.pydata.org/) for a variety of helpful table operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, for reading and writing CSV files I recommend using [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module. To separate the headers from the rest of the rows you can use [iter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) and [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) built-in functions. Calling `iter()` will give you an iterator object, and calling `next()` once will retrieve the first row from the iterator. Then, the iterator will be exhausted by the for loop. Here's an example:

```py
import csv

rows = []
with open('data.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_iter = iter(csv.reader(csv_file))
    rows.append(next(csv_iter))
    for row in csv_iter:
        total = sum(int(val) for val in row[1:])
        rows.append([*row, total])

with open('data.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv.writer(csv_file).writerows(rows)
```

Comment: Thanks, that does exactly what I wanted it to.

Answer (score 1):

1. Skip the header line by reading a line before the `for` loop.
2. You need to split the line at `,` characters before looping over it.
3. You have to convert the numbers to integers before adding them.
4. You can't write into the file while you're reading it. Opening it in `a` mode will write the totals at the end of the file, not at the end of the current line. You should append to the variable holding the current row, and then rewrite the entire file at the end.
5. You need to strip off the newline before appending to the row, and add it back when saving to write later.
6. You need to convert a number to a string to concatenate it.

Updated script:

```
all_rows = []
with open (myfile, 'r') as fin:
    all_rows.append(myfile.readline()) # Skip header line
    for row in fin:
        row.rstrip() # remove trailing newline
        line = 0

        for num in row:
            if num.isdigit():
                line += int(num)

        row += ',' + str(line) + '\n'
        all_rows.append(row)

with open (myfile, 'w') as fout:
    fout.writelines(all_rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for row in fin:
    all_numbers = [int(x) for x in row.split(',') if x.isdigit()]
    total = str(sum(all_numbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

1.You can have a variable that is false when you start, yet then is turned true in the loop like this:

```
first==False
with open (myfile, 'r') as fin:
for row in fin:
    if not first:
        first=True
    else:
        total = []
        line = 0

        for num in row:
            if num.isdigit():
                line += num

        total.append(line)

        with open (myfile, 'a') as fout:
            fout.write(',' + total)
```

2.The elements of `row` are strings. Changing it to `line+=int(num)` should fix the error.